Why are some of the boxes with VOR information thick (like IST VOR) but some of the boxes are thin (like UHM VOR)?
Why are some of the boxes with VOR information thick (like IST VOR) but some of the boxes are thin (like UHM VOR)?


According to this document the shadowed area to the right and the bottom of the box denotes that it is part of an airway.

Low and High/Low charts include a Compass Rose with VHF Navaids. Shadow box indicates navaid is airway component, with frequency, identifier, Morse code and INS coordinates

Another place in the same document also has a different but similar use of the shadow box

A shadowed navaid box indicates the primary navaid upon which lateral course guidance for the final approach segment is predicated.

